# Ignore case affect character set

Tags: java, ignore-case

I have created a binary search tree and I want to make it as efficient as possible. When adding nodes I have used `equalsIgnoreCase()` when comparing it to a `String` (To prevent duplicates).

When adding two nodes such as: `"BOB"` and `"bob"`.

For example:

converting `"BOB"` in to ASCII = 066 079 066

Converting `"bob"` in to ASCII= 098 111 098

You can see `"BOB"` and `"bob"` both have different values due to the uppercase letters.

Would `equalsIgnoreCase()` accept this as one entry regardless of the capitalisation?

Does this help efficiency?

Comment: some code would be better.

Comment: @yshavit This is a good answer. It should be an answer, not a comment!

Comment: @Keara Good point!

Comment: Also, as a formatting note to OP: digit strings that start with 0 (like 066) in Java signify octal, and three-digit numbers are often [octets](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Octet_(computing)). So a number like "066" is confusing; it looks like both an octal and an octet in decimal format, neither of which is the case here. The standard way to express this char's hex value in Java would probably be 0x0066 or 0x66.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would very likely break your binary tree. There are many values (common ones, even) that come between "bob" and "BOB" in lexicographic order. For instance: anything that starts with a lower-case "a" or an upper-case letter "C" or above. If any one of them were in your tree, then "BOB" would go in one direction at that node ("BOB" < "Dog") while "bob" would go in another ("bob" > "Dog"). That means that you wouldn't even have a chance to compare "bob" and "BOB."

You could get it to work by either:

- using [`compareToIgnoreCase(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) or
- normalizing all inputs (by using [`toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--) or [`toUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--))